# Recommended resources for "Hosted Exchange 2010" novice

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I'm experimenting with moving 2 people's personal email, calendar and contacts to a Hosted Exchange 2010 service, and it's all very new to me.

I'm struggling to find good on-line resources, such as a user manual, to tell give me an overview of the basics, and more detailed instructions.

Things I've tried:

- Started reading general info on Exchange 2010, but I don't know enough to be able to tell which bits are relevant for Hosted Exchange.
- Searched for pages involving "Hosted Exchange 2010": these all seem to come up with adverts for providers
- Searched for instructions for specific tasks, such as editing the Global Address Book, seem to entirely point to information for on-site Exchange installations.
- Occasionally I find a page that is for people actually doing the hosting
- Searched Safari Books Online - again, I can't find anything about *Hosted* Exchange.
- [Searched SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22hosted%20exchange%22) - nothing stands out
- [Searched ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22hosted%20exchange%22) - nothing stands out

Am I missing anything obvious? Can anyone please point me to any resources for *customers* of Hosted Exchange 2010?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/exchange-online-hosted-email.aspx) is an online users guide from microsoft. IMHO it does a very good job at providing an overview of the service, how it works and its offerings.

Comment: Thanks. That looks useful for finding out the capabilities, from a marketing perspective. It also told me that I need to include 'Exchange Online' in my searches. However, I can't see any links from it to how to set it up and configure it, which is really what I am looking for.

Comment: Hay you tried technet? look at this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd867691.aspx, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I must admit that because that Technet link is for BPOS, I had presumed it was not relevant for a general Hosted Exchange 2010 set-up. Similarly, I'd been presuming that links about Exchange in Office 365 were also not appropriate. Are they actually valid for standalone Hosted Exchange?

Comment: True, the hosted exchange setup depends on which company you are hosting with.Godaddy, Intermedia, Sherweb all have different back-end administration setups. I personally like BPOS. This link:http://www.petri.co.il/microsoft-bpos-hosted-services-review.htm shows a great comparison of hosting. Hosted Exchange is one of the offerings of BPOS. Office 365 is another (smaller) offering which includes other office products.